# What is the difference between "besprochen" and "gesprochen"?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences and which one is correct for a formal e-mail?

- Wie **besprochen** sende ich Ihnen meine E-Mail Adresse.
- Wie **gesprochen** sende ich Ihnen meine E-Mail Adresse.

(We had talked on the telephone, if that makes any difference.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Wie besprochen ...

is the correct one.

> Wie gesprochen ...

doesn't make sense.

"Sprechen", of which "gesprochen" is a form, focusses more on the act of speaking. "Besprechen" focusses on the topics that are spoken about.

Comment: "Wie gesprochen" macht in wenigen Ausnahmen durchaus sinn. Beispiel: "Da das Wort 'Baum' keine stummen Laute enthält, wird es geschrieben wie gesprochen."

Answer (score 8):

It's two different words: **besprochen** is the past participle of *besprechen* (*discuss*, *talk about*); **gesprochen** is the past participle of *sprechen* (*speak*, *talk*).

Answer (score 2):

- Wie besprochen -> As discussed
- Wie gesprochen -> As spoken

One should use "Wie besprochen" in German and "As discussed" in English as other sentence doesn't make much sense in both the languages.